# arch linux strange message after installing xorg and virtualbox guest additions

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, virtualbox

I'm brand new to arch linux. I'm following the tutorial first part and got a linux environment working on virtualbox 5.1.6

After that I installed xorg-server, xorg-xinit, twm, xterm, xf86-video -vesa virtualbox-guest-utils (virtualbox-guest-modules-arch)

rebooted and getting following message:

```
ACPI: No IRQ available for PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD]. Try pci=noacpi or acpi=off
A start job is running for Load Kernel Modules (3min 37s / 4min 30s).
```

and after logged in, getting this:

```
INFO: task systemd-modules:133 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
TAINTED: G          O   4.7.4-1-ARCH #1
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

Comment: You should install `virtualbox-guest-utils` with `virtualbox-guest-dkms` for modules instead.

Comment: I have installed `virtualbox-guest-utils`, `virtualbox-guest-dkms` and `linux-headers`, but still get the same message after reboot

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 4.7.x kernel got a heavily rewritten ACPI system, and 4.7.x-4.9.x kernels currently have a bug where the kernel treats the ACPI interrupt as unshareable with any other device.  I just ran cat /proc/interrupts on a fresh install, on VirtualBox (without I/O APIC) ACPI and vboxguest are both on IRQ9.  Apparently vbox modules never get their interrupt and just hang.  You can turn on I/O APIC in VirtualBox and linux will give each device it's own interrupt, a simple workaround for this bug.